# Why ksqldb is not showing streams after upgrading?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have upgraded Kafka from 5.2.2 to 5.5.1. I can see all the topics that I have made earlier but I am not being able to get streams and tables from ksqldb. Any idea?

Comment: Did you backup and restore the KSQL property file?

Comment: yes, I did that still not working. Even I tried by creating a new stream from the previous topic. Data are there on the topic but when I queried the newly made stream from the previous topic, the query doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data directory in Kafka config (log.dirs). What you can do is if you still have your older kafka directory available then map log.dirs in Kafka 5.5.1 to the older directory and then restart your kafka and ksqldb.

Sometime /tmp directory can be of trouble which gets cleaned on system reboot. Better is to move data directory to some other folder in home or var.

Comment: Actually I have done all these things that you have asked me to do but it's not working either.